# Python/Javascript number precision

Tags: javascript, python

Probably this question is already existed somewhere but can't find my specific issue.

I have a two numbers that I want to add and I don't want to use **round()** function since I am working with money.

```
1.70 + 1.44 = 3.14 //Returns 3.1399999999999997
1.70 + 1.45 = 3.15 //Returns the correct answer
1.70 + 1.37 = 3.07 //Returns 3.0700000000000003
```

I tried it in Javascript but still the same issue.

Comment: Simple solution: do your calculations in integer by converting to, e.g., dollar to cents.

Comment: [This](http://floating-point-gui.de/) site might explain why the issue occurs, and how to solve it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're working with money, always use the `decimal.Decimal` class in Python.

Comment: Yeah. I did it like this instead of calculating it in front end.

Answer (score 0):

Use `parseFloat` to precision :

```
parseFloat(number).toFixed(precision);
```

E.g.

```
parseFloat(1.70 + 1.37).toFixed(2);  // RETURN 3.07
```

Answer (score 0):

one way you can achieve this is to multiply the values by (10 * precision) that you need and then divide the result by (10 * precision).

- ((1.70 * 100) + (1.37 * 100))/100 = 3.07
- ((1.70 * 100) + (1.45 *  100))/100 = 3.15
- ((1.70 * 100) + (1.44 * 100))/100 = 3.14

you can add a method to do this for you to keep it simple.